# Stream youtube sound via Ruby?

Tags: ruby, youtube, streaming

I'm trying to build a music player/playlist maker with Ruby and TK. I still haven't figured out a way to stream the youtube video (actually only the sound) I don't want to download and then play the song, cause that would take too long. And I couldn't find any information regarding streaming directly without some kind of embedded player.

Does anyone know how I could best tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an intersting project, so I searched a little. From this reddit post: [Tip: Use mpv + youtube-dl as streaming audio player](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/35botl/tip_use_mpv_youtubedl_as_streaming_audio_player/) there's this code using the `mpv` program to stream audio:

```
mpv "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVK5Z6wnMxg" --no-video
```

That URL is a livestream of the Bonaroo music festical that's currently happening. I tried it and it does start the audio. Under the hood this is using [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) which has this note in the man page:

> How do I stream directly to media player?
>
> You will first need to tell youtube-dl to  stream
>              media to stdout with -o -, and also tell your me‐
>              dia player to read from stdin (it must be capable
>              of  this  for  streaming) and then pipe former to
>              latter.    For   example,   streaming   to    vlc
>              (http://www.videolan.org/) can be achieved with:
>
> youtube-dl -o - "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKcj" | vlc -

So if you wanted to pass the stream to a different media player, that would be a good place to start.

In terms of Ruby; well, this isn't really a Ruby solution per se, and you'd simply call the shell program from Ruby using backticks, `system`, `Process.spawn`, `fork`, etc.

Comment: There's also [Open3](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Open3.html) which gives you more direct control over the output of system commands.

Comment: Oh nice I did some further digging too and found [this](https://github.com/woodruffw/ruby-mpv) ruby library for controlling MPV. It's lacking a bit of documentation but I think I can use that, or like you said, pass the stream. Marking your solution as an answer. Thank you!